# Storing documents with different structure in same Azure COSMOS DB container

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

Considering COSMOS DB as No-Sql document based database, would it be a good idea to store different documents, with different structure.

Comment: There's really no single right answer to this, especially since we know nothing of your document shapes, query patterns, etc. Ultimately, the decision will be up to you and your app's needs. Perhaps edit your question to show specifics?

Comment: Also, I would suggest reading up on some of the data modeling articles written specifically for Cosmos DB, to get a better idea of what to consider, aside from purely data shape (e.g. partitioning).